# Gitlab: add all users to all groups without changing permisions of existing users

Tags: gitlab, administration

In GitLab you can add all users to all groups with a simple command:

```
 gitlab-rake gitlab:import:all_users_to_all_groups
```

After execution the GitLab *Users* became **developers** and GitLab *administrators* become **owners** of each group. If there were existing users in the group with different permissions, the permissions are discarded with this command.

The question is if there is a command to add all users to all groups where:

- command would add only the users which are not already in the group or
- command would add all users, but remain existing permissions which were already attributed to the users in the groups

Answer (score 2):

> The question is if there is a command to add all users to all groups where...

All the user management functions are in [`lib/tasks/gitlab/bulk_add_permission.rake`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/91fa250038e9182988319f088fb84741b6e2efc9/lib/tasks/gitlab/bulk_add_permission.rake#L24-L36), including [`all_users_to_all_groups`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/91fa250038e9182988319f088fb84741b6e2efc9/lib/tasks/gitlab/bulk_add_permission.rake#L24-L36)

You could modify that file and implement a function that would not just call `group.add_users(user_ids, GroupMember::DEVELOPER)` but check its rights first.